# Retrieving invalid syntax running python script inside docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I have the following code I am running inside a docker container and I am new to docker containers, which is continuously listening to user input. I run the python code inside the running docker container like this python command-interface.py

While running on docker container it gives a syntax error.

```
import zmq
import time 
CLIENT_COMMAND_HANDLER_ADDRESS = "tcp://localhost:5554"
context = zmq.Context()
handler_socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
def main():
  """main function for initiating the script."""
  handler_socket.connect(CLIENT_COMMAND_HANDLER_ADDRESS)
  running = True
  print(f"{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')} ( + ) :  Connected.")

  while running:
    command = input(">  ")
    command = command.encode()
    
    if command == "exit":
        handler_socket.close()
        running = False
        return
    handler_socket.send(command)
    response = handler_socket.recv().decode()
    print(f"{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')} ( Client ) :  {response}  ")
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Error

```
  while running:
  Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

Help is highly appreciated thanks

Comment: looks like `while running:` has not the right indentation

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel, its a typo mistake when I posted the question here but in the code its not an indentation issue

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run the code outside Docker?  If not, what in the Docker environment is different (for example, can you include your image's Dockerfile)?  Can you include the complete error message?